# mongoose - increment a value inside an array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
  "name": String,
  "users": [
     { 
       "user_id": ObjectId,
       "counter": Number
     }]
});
```

example of a document:

```
{
   "name": "Test",
   "users": [
       {
          "user_id": "aaaaaa",
          "counter": 2
       },
       {
          "user_id": "bbbbbb",
          "counter": 3
       }]
}
```

How can i `findOneAndUpdate` a specific `user_id` and increment `counter`?

For example: how can i find `Test` and update the `counter`of `user_id: bbbbb` in a single action?

Comment: so far i'm doing 2 queries which i want to avoid: finding the document with "Test". then going over the array and updating the specific counter. and then save
i'm not sure how to do this in one query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mongoose.model('MySchema', mySchema); //is this line superflous??
var MySchema = mongoose.model('MySchema');

MySchema.update({"name": "Test", "users.user_id" : "aaaaaa" } , 
                {$inc : {"users.$.counter" : 1} },
                function() {...});
```

So with first object you are finding object that you want to update. Second parameter is what you want to update, where $ is used to change only currently selected object in query. Last parameter is callback.